# Failed to install MPX Runtime Driver (for bounds checking)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, windows-10, bounds-checker

After reading [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/01/20/visual-studio-2015-update-1-new-experimental-feature-mpx/) on detecting memory leaks I decided to install the MPX runtime driver from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-memory-protection-extensions-enabling-guide). I right-clicked mpxruntime.inf and selected "install". The Device manager then lists "Intel(R) MPX Runtime Driver" under system devices, but its icon has a little exclamation mark on a yellow triangle. If I right-click on the icon and select properties, I see the following text:

```
This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

{Operation Failed}
The requested operation was unsuccessful.
```

I am clueless as to what to try at this point.

FYI: I am running windows 10 with an i7 6850K processor.

**EDIT:** Looking at the processor with the [CPU-Z utility](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), it has an area called "Instructions" listing things like MMX,SSE,VT-x,AES, TSX,... etc. but MPX does not appear in that list. Maybe that's telling me my processor does not have MPX instructions?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the latest [Intel® Software Development Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator).
2. Use Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, that emits MPX code, to create an executable test.exe

   ```
   char buffer[100];
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {          
      buffer[100] = 0;
     return 0;
   }
   ```
3. try it by running:

   ```
   sde -- test.exe
   ```

Useful links:

- [Windows 10 Anniversary Update](http://www.windowscentral.com/windowscentral.com/windows-10-anniversary-update)
- [Using Intel® MPX with the Intel® Software Development Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mpx-with-the-intel-software-development-emulator)

Comment: First I uninstalled the MPX driver. Then I installed the Intel software development emulator, then I tried to reinstall the MPX driver. When I right-click mpxruntime.inf and select install, windows reports "The operation completed successfully" but then MPX is nowhere to be seen under "system devices".

Comment: @Mick the MPX runtime driver is not needed, when you run under the device emulator. It should work even on other systems than Windows 10. The MPX runtime driver is for Windows 10 Anniversary Update only.

Comment: I got as far as reading the lines "one must link in an object file version of the loadrt.cpp file supplied in our MPX runtime download zip file. This example uses a version of ICL that is not available externally yet."  - neither mpx.obj or loadrt.obj were anywhere on my system. Am I right in thinking that you are suggesting this "emulation" route because MPX is not actually built into my i7-6850K processor?

Comment: I suggested the emulation route because I noticed too late the information about your processor. The i7-6850K should have MPX built in. https://ark.intel.com/products/88969/Intel-Core-i7-6820HK-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz I will try myself, in the following days, the driver route, and will post any findings here.